# Why did my favicon stop working when the code hasn't been changed?

Tags: icons, loading, favicon, bookmarks, favorite

A couple weeks ago I noticed that the favicon stopped loading for my website: http://makingspidersense.com/Schubert/

I haven't changed the code for that section and the png file still exists on the server. It appears that all the tags are properly closed. This code used to work and still works just fine for my other websites. So what caused it to stop loading and how do I fix it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/schubert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="description" content="The official website for Schubert's Hartford Theatre in Hartford, WI. Purchase your tickets online, find showtimes, movie trailers, shows that are coming soon, discount prices and more!" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Schubert, Theatres, Cinemas, tickets, showtimes, movies, Hartford, WI" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ben.moran.28" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1075px"/>
<title>Schubert's Hartford Theatre in WI - Purchase tickets, find showtimes and movie info</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/coin-slider.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>
```

Comment: I have had this problem in the past but it appeared to be due to my browser saving a older version of the favicon that was no longer available. Try deleting your cookies and trying again :D

Comment: Cleared my cookies and cache still does work. Also tried it on another computer and multiple browsers (chrome and firefox). Were you able to see the favicon?

Comment: Sorry can't see it either :( but cool website! :D

Comment: Curious what happens if you change it to: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Just tried that too and it's still not showing up. :/

Comment: Yea, not sure on this one then.  The favicon thing has always seemed like a half-working feature to me.  I think your best bet is to just put it as `/favicon.ico` and don't put anything in your HTML.  That usually works.

Answer (score 0):

When I go to your website I get this as your head:

```
<head>
  <title>Schubert Theatres </title>

</head>
```

I have not worked with frameset before, and it seems that the rest of your website is shown via a frameset of some type, but I would suggest trying to put the icon in the actual head of your page. That could help.

Comment: That's just what shows up because I provided a domain (schuberttheatres.com) that points to the actual website. The actual url is http://makingspidersense.com/Schubert/ which I updated in the post.